# Is it possible to have Gmail display messages in alternating colors?

Tags: gmail, gmail-themes

Is there a theme or a workaround available to display e-mails in my inbox in alternating colors (e.g. odd and even lines differ in coloring)?

Comment: FYI, the proper term is zebra stripes.

Comment: @dnbrv source? as far as I know zebras only come in black and white.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a custom stylesheet (CSS) to do this. Just apply the styles

```
.zA:nth-child(2n) {
    background-color: /*even color*/ !important;
}
.zA:nth-child(2n+1) {
    background-color: /*odd color*/ !important;
}
```

with colors of your choice. (The class you need to use may vary — it was `y0` for me and `zA` for the OP.)

([Here are](http://blog.persistent.info/2004/10/skinning-gmail-with-custom-stylesheet.html) instructions for custom stylesheets in Firefox; other browsers may have other extensions which let you do this.)

Comment: I found an add-on (Stylish) that allows for custom style-sheets in Firefox (URLid that the instruction link pointed to does not seem to exist anymore). The styles you mentioned did not seem to work though. I am able to change some styles so the script works, but I'd gladly accept help to find the styles required for the inbox lines.

Comment: I found the `.y0` class by using the WebKit Web Inspector to look at the rows of the inbox. In Firefox you can use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to look around and see if they are different for you.

Comment: After updating the custom stylesheet to use the zA class, it worked! Much obliged.